WebStorm resets browser settings with every new version
I use WebStorm with an Angular application and a Run/Debug Configuration like so:

In that browser, I use customs settings:

hide all unnecessary icons in the tool bar
several extensions (ColorZilla, GraphQL Network Inspector, etc)
custom device in devtool device emulation (1920x970, desktop type)
etc.

However, after every new WebStorm version, whenever I use the Debug Configuration, all my custom settings are gone and I have to set them up all over again. A login with an account in the browser is not an option due to privacy reasons.
Is there any way to keep my browser settings/customizations after a WebStorm update? Thanks in advance.

What/where it resets exactly? In the actual browser profile .. or in the WebStorm settings? If it's browser -- it should not do that (never heard of); maybe it just uses a different profile -- double check that. Check the following link as well on how to point to a custom profile -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-debugger.html#ws_js_debug_default_chrome_user_data

It's in the browser itself (e.g. toolbar adjustments). The browser looks and is set up like a fresh install. Regarding your shared link: I do not use any custom settings: https://i.imgur.com/iX4dOCh.png

Well ... I do not know how the IDE can reset the browser settings then. I suggest the following: 1) make a custom profile in your Browser and configure it it all there 2) then set up custom browser in WebStorm and tell it to use that profile (as per the link). Other than that -- contact JetBrains Support (Help | Contact Support...)
